# What to do with an underground pool outlet now that the pool is gone

Tags: receptacle, pool

I took down a pool that has an underground wire( through conduit) that has an electrical outlet that supplied power to the pump. What can I do to terminate the outlet ? 
The yard is set to be filled and graded and I would like to bury the wiring. Can I do that??

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm no expert, but my guess is "no way"; let's see what our pros have to say. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Do you want to bury the wiring to "make it go away"? Or bury the wiring to some useful destination where you'll put an outlet etc.?

Comment: Be sure you really don't want to use it.  Outdoor power can be useful, and you can always move it some rather than abandoning it.

Answer (score 3):

The only safe thing to do is to **disconnect the wires at the other end**. That could be:

- The main panel
- A subpanel
- A junction box - e.g., the wires might come out of the ground next to the house and go into a junction box to splice to another set of wires that go to the main panel

If you disconnect any place other than a panel (which obviously would be accessible), the remaining location (e.g., another junction box) must be accessible. Cap any remaining wires with wire nuts so they can't touch anything else in the panel or box and cause a problem.

Comment: I always like to cut the end going into the yard too short to easily just hook back up, and properly label it “abandoned underground”.  Pull the feeder out of the panel or junction box and physically make it hard to reconnect by cutting it off.  The problem with just unhooking and capping, is that in the future (say 20 years) someone’s trying to troubleshoot an unrelated electrical problem and says “I’ll just hook this up, I wonder why someone disconnected it.”  Sure, the person that blindly reconnects it is an idiot, but it’s better to make it clear the wire has been abandoned.

Comment: The only safe thing is to remove the wire.

Comment: You can certainly cut off as much of the wire from the other end (panel or junction box) as you can reach. Actually **removing** the wire may not be practical. If it is in conduit then that **should** be easy - disconnect both ends and pull. But if there are hidden (shouldn't be, but...) bends then that it may not pull easily. And if it is buried cable rather than wires through conduit then pulling won't work at all.